# Save default installed sounds on Original Droid

Tags: audio, motorola-droid, backup, ringtone

I have an original Motorola Droid. Is there a way I can save all the original pre-installed sounds/ringtones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all of the default ringtones and notification sound files are in `/system/media/audio`.

If you can't get to them when mounting via USB, you should be able to use something like ASTRO file manager to copy the files to your SD card and then get them that way. They just appear to be ogg files.